# macro vlookup on blank cells only

Tags: vba

I'm having troubles with vlookup function on blank cells.

I have 2 columns  A and B. B is the column I will apply vlookup on and column A contents with "lookup value"

The table array range is d2:e7

My macro:

```
Sub a()
    Dim x As Range
    Set x = Range("b2:b7").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    x = Application.VLookup(Range("a2:a7"), Range("d2:e7"), 2, False)
End Sub
```

I tried to run this code so many times but it always came out wrong. Can you guys help me out?

#### Screenshot: Sample Data

[image: Screenshot: Sample Data]

Comment: There are no blanks in your column A range. All your shown values have a matching lookup value. What is strange is you have 'e' as a return value for numerous different lookup values.

Comment: You cannot do array type formulas, like this.  either loop through the range and put the values in one by one or put a formula in as @QHarr has shown.

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner, can you show me how to loop through the range, i've tried something like "for each next" but the result is not pretty

Answer (score 1):

After becoming more familiar with VBA, the code that works for me is:

```
    Sub a()
    For i = 2 To 7
    If Sheet1.Cells(i, 2) = "" Then Sheet1.Cells(i, 2) = 
    Application.VLookup(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1), Sheet1.Range("d2:e7"), 2, 0)
    Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you simply mean

```
 Sub a()
      ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B7").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],R2C4:R7C5,2,FALSE)"
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you QHarr but can you do it with vba vlookup application